# Beginner's guide to Feature flags - Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, gargoyle

I am trying to understand Django's [Gargoyle](https://github.com/disqus/gargoyle) library - a feature flag library and cannot wrap my head around as to how it should be implemented. Does anyone know of any tutorial or can guide me how to go about it?

Also, if anyone has experience implementing a feature flag library apart from [Gargoyle](https://github.com/disqus/gargoyle) and thinks it has better documentation and ease of use than Gargoyle, please do share.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a Django feature switcher sample [here](https://github.com/configcat/python-sdk/tree/master/samples/webappsample).

This is how you can check the feature flags in the [sample-code](https://github.com/configcat/python-sdk/blob/b9ce8873998fa17ffd261c0535494ccedac5225c/samples/webappsample/webapp/views.py#L14-L16).

You can manage your feature flags on [configcat.com](https://configcat.com).

Answer (score 3):

Django waffle is also a well maintained feature switcher: [django-waffle](https://github.com/jsocol/django-waffle)